# AMF client in Java

Tags: java, blazeds, amf

I am using [BlazeDS java client](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Java+AMF+Client) to get info from [this page](http://orlandoinfo.com/attractions/).
This page has a form in the middle that when you select a type, the location combo on the button gets updated.

I am trying to use BlazeDS to get those values in java.
I have been using [Charles web proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to debug, and this are the screenshots from [the request](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/8751/request.png) and [the response](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/586/response.png):

My code so far is the following:

```
        // Create the AMF connection.
        AMFConnection amfConnection = new AMFConnection();

        // Connect to the remote url.
        String url = "http://orlandoinfo.com/flex2gateway/";
        try
        {
            amfConnection.connect(url);
        }
        catch (ClientStatusException cse)
        {
            System.out.println(cse);
            return;
        }

        // Make a remoting call and retrieve the result.
        try
        {
//          amfConnection.registerAlias("flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection", "flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection");
            amfConnection.call("ColdFusion.getLocations", new Object[] {"consumer", "attractions", "ATTR"});

        }

        catch (ClientStatusException cse)
        {
            System.out.println(cse);
        }
        catch (ServerStatusException sse)
        {
            System.out.println(sse);
        }

        // Close the connection.
        amfConnection.close();
```

When I run it I get a:

```
ServerStatusException 
    data: ASObject(15401342){message=Unable to find source to invoke, rootCause=null, details=null, code=Server.Processing}
    HttpResponseInfo: HttpResponseInfo 
    code: 200
    message: OK
```

Can anyone spot what's wrong?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: That is a client side error message, yes?  Can you please post anything interesting from the server side logs?

Comment: I don't access to the server. The web is not mine.

Comment: If you don't have access to the server, then does that mean you don't have permission to be going this?  **This question now smells like illicit reverse engineering to me.**  Evil.

Comment: @Stu: I checked robots.txt and I don't think this is disallow.
Perhaps I don't have permission to do it so, but I think that reproducing AMF params is like reproducing an HTTP POST.

(I deleted my last comment because when I re-read it, it sounded offensive.)

Comment: **Check the ToC**. That is where things like this are located. Write them if you aren't sure. And check the `crossdomain.xml`.  Is your site in there? Your analogy `HTTP POST` doesn't really hold, frankly. Having your own website with HTTP POSTs into orlandoinfo.com is dodgy if the user never ends up there. It is not the same as linking. If you don't have permission to query the API, then you are basically stealing other folks content. If your case is legit, I'll continue to help...but at this point it sounds really dodgy.

Comment: Additionally, `robots.txt` is not some universal *"what you can hit programatically"* or *"what not"*.  It is specifically for indexing spiders, and spiders generally do not make random `AMF` calls.  (Unless you are writing an AMF calling spider???)

Comment: @Stu: I think what I mention about HTTP POST was misunderstood. My point is: If it's ok to programatically see how an HTTP POST is done to a website and get some info to do a spider (always taking into account robots.txt), why would it be wrong to do AMF calls instead?

I am not trying to do anything ilegal but perhaps I should contact the site owner to see if it's allright to do it.

Comment: Basic `crossdomain.xml` security would not allow what you are trying to do in a Flash player, if you were coding in Flash, Flex or AS3.  Check it out at http://www.orlandoinfo.com/crossdomain.xml  ...you can see who they explicitly allow to use their API.  While this security is technically weak, it demonstrates intent.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about the existance of crossdomain.xml. Please reply this question with your last comment and I will check it as answered.
Thanks for your time Stu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using Charles Web Proxy. Sniffing AMF parameters and running my code with `-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1  -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888`

I compare both calls and modify to look alike.
The working code looks like this:

```
String url = "http://www.theGateWayurl.com";
// Generates the connection to the amf gateway.
AMFConnection amfConnection = new AMFConnection();

// Must register the class that this library will use to load the
// AMF object information.
// The library will read AMF object variables and use setters from
// the java bean stated in this line.
AMFConnection.registerAlias("", new LabelData().getClass().getName());

try {
    // Do the connection.
    amfConnection.connect(url);

    // This page requires a certain headers to function.
    // The Content-type is used to sniff with Charles Web Proxy.
    amfConnection.addHttpRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-amf");
    // The Referer is used by the webpage to allow gathering information.
    amfConnection.addHttpRequestHeader("Referer", "http://orlandoinfo.com/ws/b2c/sitesearch/customtags/comSearch.swf");

    // The rest of the HTTP POST sent by this library is wrapped
    // inside a RemotingMessage.
    // Prepare the msg to send.
    RemotingMessage msg = new RemotingMessage();

    // The method called in the server.
    msg.setOperation("getLocations");

    // Where the request came from. Similar to referer.
    msg.setSource("ws.b2c.sitesearch.components.myService");

    // The destination is a needed parameter.
    msg.setDestination("ColdFusion");

    // Create the body with the parameters needed to call the
    // operation set with setOperation()
    msg.setBody(new Object[] {"consumer", "attractions"});

    // This is needed but not used.
    msg.setMessageId("xxxxxxxxxx");

    // Send the msg.
    AcknowledgeMessage reply = (AcknowledgeMessage) amfConnection.call("null", msg);

    // Parse the reply from the server.
    ArrayCollection body = (ArrayCollection) reply.getBody();
    for (Object obj : body) {
        LabelData location = (LabelData) obj;
        // Do something with the info.
    }

} catch (ClientStatusException cse) {
    // Do something with the exception.

} catch (ServerStatusException sse) {
    // Do something with the exception.
} finally {
    amfConnection.close();
}
```

The LabelData is just a java bean with with two vars: Data and Label.
I tried to comment every line for a better understanding.
Take into account what Stu mention in previous comments about crossdomain.xml to see if you have the rights to do this kind of things.

Comment: @Marcarse - Recently I asked a question over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552409/how-to-make-a-producer-consumer-java-client-for-blazeds , and I think your answer is close to my attempt at java only client. Basically I need a AcknowledgeMessage in response to a CommandMessage ping but are receiving ASObject. I feel this is needed to obtain DSId which is sent through subsequent requests with jessionid. Do think it possible to have pure java client for blazeds?

Comment: @MikeW: Sorry but I have no idea. I did this a long time ago :(